# Make player move forward,right,left and backwards based on camera angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So far I have a player who moved forward left right and backwards, however how I have it set up it's forward as in forward on the grid, not forward where my player is looking. I have the camera set as FPS, with it following the player around. Now I want to have the player be able to look with my MouseLook script (works already) but based on that I want forward to be wherever the player is looking, not the primitive version I have. I'll post code below to let you know what I am talking about, ANY help is appreciated.

Player Script (movement)

```
    void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey (moveU))
    {
        SetTransformZ((transform.position.z) + playerSpeed);

    }

    if(Input.GetKey (moveD))
    {
        SetTransformZ((transform.position.z) - playerSpeed);

    }

    if(Input.GetKey (moveL))
    {
        SetTransformX((transform.position.x) - playerSpeed);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (moveR))
    {
        SetTransformX((transform.position.x) + playerSpeed);
    }

    else
    {
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    }


}

void SetTransformX(float n)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(n, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}

void SetTransformZ(float n)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, n);
}
```

MouseLook script (attached to Main Camera in Unity, this works witht he player so it goes whereever my mouse is looking, but the movement is off since my code to move is very primitive)

```
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

public enum RotationAxes { 
    MouseXAndY = 0, 
    MouseX = 1, 
    MouseY = 2 }

public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;
public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;
public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;
float rotationY = 0F;

void Update ()      
{
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
    {
        float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    }

    else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
    }

    else
    {
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}



void Start ()
{
    //if(!networkView.isMine)
    //enabled = false;

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    //if (rigidbody)
    //rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;

}
```

Comment: So it's first person, do you rotate your player as the camera rotates?

Comment: Wow yeah it should be on my Player, made the switch, but that still won't solve my issue, however big mistake on my part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so you want your player to move forward, left, right, back relative to where they are looking, as I understand it.

First, make sure that `transform.forward` is the right direction for your player. in the editor you can select your player `gameObject` and see if the **blue arrow** faces the same direction as your player. If not, check out [this thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205535/what-is-the.html) on the unity answers forum to see how to change it.

Here are some functions to put into your player controller script to move relative to player rotation rather than position.
(Note: check out [Time.deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html))

```
private void moveForward(float speed) {
    transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

private void moveBack(float speed) {
    transform.localPosition -= transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

private void moveRight(float speed) {
    transform.localPosition += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

private void moveLeft(float speed) {
    transform.localPosition -= transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Note: [transform.position vs transform.localPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html)

Comment: Awesome man! Now I have a rigidbody for my Player, and I have it blocking Y movement, I'm assuming these functions override that, is there any way to not have him move up or down on the Y axis?

Comment: I believe `transform.forward` and `transform.right` both have `.y` = `0f`. If so it shouldn't move on `y` at all.

Comment: That's weird then because when I look up and move forward it goes up y axis. i'll mess around with it more, very thankful for this script!

Comment: oh, I see, because when you look up the player's forward is pointing up. You can fix that by altering the script that rotates your player. Change it so that it **only** rotates on the **y axis**